# System updates, now config page errors, drush ends abnormally

Tags: routes, drush, composer

After an update failed I'm seeing the following issues. I have tried several things to recover. I do have a database backup, but I am not sure on how to restore using Drush (and I'm concerned because Drush is not working properly).

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "markdown.overview" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 208 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).
> Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->getRoute('markdown.overview') (Line: 271)
> Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('markdown.overview', Array, Array, 1) (Line: 105)
> Drupal\Core\Render\MetadataBubblingUrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('markdown.overview', Array, Array, ) (Line: 762)
> Drupal\Core\Url->toString() (Line: 135)
> markdown_requirements('runtime')
> call_user_func_array('markdown_requirements', Array) (Line: 403)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll('requirements', Array) (Line: 111)
> Drupal\system\SystemManager->listRequirements() (Line: 95)
> Drupal\system\SystemManager->checkRequirements() (Line: 121)
> Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController->overview('system.admin_config')
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 573)
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 151)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

The out of `drush cr` is the following.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/modules/ludwig/src/Controller/PackageController.php on line 84
> Drush command terminated abnormally.

The error log contains the following error message.

> ParseError: syntax error, unexpected ')' in Composer\Autoload\includeFile() (line 84 of /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/modules/ludwig/src/Controller/PackageController.php)
> #0 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/apps/myapps/ht...')
> #1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Drupal\ludwig\C...')
> #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Drupal\ludwig\C...')
> #3 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php(136): ReflectionMethod->__construct('\Drupal\ludwig\...', 'page')
> #4 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php(221): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityResolverManager->setParametersFromReflection(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Route))
> #5 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EntityRouteAlterSubscriber.php(48): Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityResolverManager->setRouteOptions(Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\Route))
> #6 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EntityRouteAlterSubscriber->onRoutingRouteAlterSetType(Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent), 'routing.route_a...', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
> #7 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): call_user_func(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent), 'routing.route_a...', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
> #8 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(189): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('routing.route_a...', Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent))
> #9 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(83): Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild()
> #10 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/includes/common.inc(1090): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild()
> #11 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/includes/batch.inc(295): drupal_flush_all_caches(Array)
> #12 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/includes/batch.inc(137): _batch_process()
> #13 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/includes/batch.inc(93): _batch_do()
> #14 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/modules/system/src/Controller/DbUpdateController.php(185): _batch_page(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
> #15 [internal function]: Drupal\system\Controller\DbUpdateController->handle('start', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
> #16 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Update/UpdateKernel.php(115): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> #17 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Update/UpdateKernel.php(76): Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
> #18 /apps/myapps/html/test/drupal/update.php(28): Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
> #19 {main}

Comment: What update failed?  It looks like you have a problem with your code, so it doesn't matter if you reset the database; this problem will continue to occur until you fix the code problem.  It may be that you installed incompatible versions of modules/core; make a backup of all the files and then try running `composer install`.

Comment: Look at the file named in the PHP Parse error. Maybe be incomplete or a typo went in their somehow.

Comment: @leymannx I ended up uninstalling Ludwig successfully, which seems to have mostly resolved the issue